# SQL Server : cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012 I have this query:

```
select * 
from InquiryLog i
left join Employee e on i.QueriedByEmployeeName = (e.Firstname + ' ' + e.LastName)
```

but I get this error

> Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You solve it using the `COLLATE` keyword.  Learn about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: You can just add a COLLATE [YourCollationHere] to one of the columns. This happens when you are trying to join on two columns and the collation of those columns is incompatible. You have to help it know how to resolve the collation.

Comment: what do I COLLATE  it to?

Comment: both are text columns

Comment: Actually there are three columns there. And hopefully you aren't using the text datatype and you said text but the real datatype is varchar.

Comment: no its like nvarchar and varchar

Comment: The types really need to be the same or that query is going to be really inefficient... everything should be varchar or everything should be nvarchar (and preferably the same maximum lengths as well). You can see what the collations are if you SELECT * FROM INFROMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (N'InquiryLog', N'Employee') … the collation will be listed in the results for each column in those two tables. Or you could choose DATABASE_DEFAULT as your collation (the one SQL Server was installed with).

Answer (score 1):

Using your query as an example you need to use the COLLATE keyword. Not sure what collations you have but something close to this should work for you.

```
select * 
from InquiryLog i
left join Employee e on i.QueriedByEmployeeName = (e.Firstname + ' ' + e.LastName) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: either that or you can simply say COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT and it should work

Comment: @Harry true. Ideally the columns in a join would use the same collation and datatype (in this case the OP stated that one is nvarchar and the other is varchar).